# @@for is not a function (evaluating '(typeof Symbol === 'function' ? Symbol.for: '@@for')('jest.asymmetricMater')')

Tags: android, react-native, jestjs

I'm attempting to run a react-native (0.45.1) app which is able to compile correctly on iOS, but fails to compile on android and gives us the following...

`@@for is not a function (evaluating '(typeof Symbol === 'function' ? Symbol.for: '@@for')('jest.asymmetricMater')')`

Has anyone come across this before?

[image: error]

Answer (score 7):

You probably just need to add babel-polyfill

```
npm install --save-dev babel-polyfill
```

and then

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
```

in your App entry point

Comment: We had an issue with the ordering of the import statement. Placing the import before any others fixed the issue.

Comment: Interesting, fixes my problem as well. Do you know why is it happening? I have never had to install a babel polyfill in my index to avoid some similar errors.